# Run multiple instances of an app all real time in android

Tags: android, open-source, api, google-apps, android-emulator

I want to run multiple instances of an android app at the same time and all in real time .

What's the best things I can do ?

I tried using Nox player but it uses too much resource and only can run one instance of an app at the same time.